# Reading tricky XML with XPATH

Tags: python, lxml

I am a beginner in Python & XPATH and need to read an XML with non-uniform nodes (similar to the one mentioned below) using XPATH. The output format to be written to the file is also shown below. The code uses lxml library.

Please help me build a correct XPATH.

Source XML

```
<Classes>
    <German>
        <Student>
            <Span><a href="">John</a></Span>
        </Student>
        <Student>
            <Span>Adam</Span>
        </Student>
    </German>
    <English>
        <Student>
            <Span>Mary</Span>
        </Student>
    </English>
    <French>
        <Student>
            <Span><a href="">Anil</a></Span>
        </Student>
        <Student>
            <Span><a href="">Jack</a></Span>
        </Student>
    </French>
    <Spanish>
        <Student>
            <Span>Mary</Span>
        </Student>
        <Student>
            <Span>Jack</Span>
        </Student>
    </Spanish>
</Classes>
```

Expected output

```
German
    John
    Adam
English
    Mary
French
    Anil
    Jack
Spanish
    Mary
    Jack
```

Thanks,
Nikhil

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what exactly is the problem with it - how does the output you're getting now differ from what you expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This code will help:**

```
from lxml import html

xml_content = """<Classes>
    <German>
        <Student>
            <Span><a href="">John</a></Span>
        </Student>
        <Student>
            <Span>Adam</Span>
        </Student>
    </German>
    <English>
        <Student>
            <Span>Mary</Span>
        </Student>
    </English>
    <French>
        <Student>
            <Span><a href="">Anil</a></Span>
        </Student>
        <Student>
            <Span><a href="">Jack</a></Span>
        </Student>
    </French>
    <Spanish>
        <Student>
            <Span>Mary</Span>
        </Student>
        <Student>
            <Span>Jack</Span>
        </Student>
    </Spanish>
</Classes>"""

tree = html.fromstring(xml_content)
classes = tree.xpath('//classes/*')
for language_class in classes:
    print language_class.tag.capitalize()
    for student in language_class.xpath('.//student/span//text()'):
        print "    {}".format(student)
```

**Output:**

```
German
    John
    Adam
English
    Mary
French
    Anil
    Jack
Spanish
    Mary
    Jack
```

Comment: @Nikhil my pleasure. I'm glad that my answer helped.